# How I synchronize my bullet across the network smoothly in PUN 2 unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon-pun

I am currently working on a 2D multiplayer game in Unity using Photon Unity Networking 2 (PUN 2). In my game, I have implemented projectile bullets that players can shoot. I have attached a PhotonView and TransformViewClassic to the bullet GameObject to synchronize its position and movement across the network.

However, during testing, I noticed significant lag and jitteriness in the network synchronization of the bullets. This has negatively impacted the overall gameplay experience.

Here are the key components and settings I have in place:

PhotonView attached to the bullet GameObject.
TransformViewClassic to synchronize position and movement.
[Include any relevant code snippets related to bullet instantiation and movement synchronization.]
I have tried adjusting various parameters and settings, but the issue persists. I am looking for guidance on how to achieve smooth network synchronization for 2D projectile bullets in Unity PUN 2.

Some specific questions I have:

Are there any specific settings or configurations I should be aware of when synchronizing 2D projectile bullets in a PUN 2 environment?
Are there common pitfalls or best practices for achieving smooth network synchronization in Unity PUN 2?
Are there alternative approaches or components that might be more suitable for synchronizing fast-moving 2D projectiles?
Any insights, code examples, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Feel free to modify the template based on your specific details and requirements. Additionally, make sure to provide any relevant code snippets or configurations you've tried to give potential answerers more context.

Comment: `Include any relevant code snippets related to bullet instantiation and movement synchronization.` .. could you do that maybe? Also from my experience: Yes the built-in `TransformView` etc are not very good.. implement your own through the [IPunObservable](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/interface_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_i_pun_observable.html) .. or alternatively try the [SmoothSyncMovement](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_utility_scripts_1_1_smooth_sync_movement.html) component instead